# How to integrate friend list feature in an Android App?

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to have a friend list feature in my App. The idea is to select any contact from your contact list and then that contact would be sent an SMS from the App(via Server), requesting him to click on the link to accept the friend request, if he is already on the App. If he is not on the App, the SMS would send him a download link. How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So far, when I select the contact, it gets added in my friend list, with an "!" mark that the request has not been approved at the other end. The other guy gets an SMS as well from the App(via Server) to accept the request by clicking on the link. Now when the other guy, clicks on the link(just a demo link as of now), how do I make him accept the request? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @progsource: So far, when I select the contact, it gets added in my friend list, with an "!" mark that the request has not been approved at the other end. The other guy gets an SMS as well from the App(via Server) to accept the request by clicking on the link. Now when the other guy, clicks on the link(just a demo link as of now), how do I make him accept the request? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I fail to understand that if people cannot answer then question, why do they downvote. We are here to learn and downvoting, without even answering is pathetic!

Comment: One reason for a downvote, as the tooltip says, is that a question does not show any research effort. Now please tell us, how an _“I want this […], how can I achieve it”_ type of question shows _any research effort_ in your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nearly completed the job at hand.
Here is what you can do to finish it.
You will need to maintain a mapping of which number sent which other number a link on the server. I have not understood how a single link for all requests is going to suffice what you need to do(else you will need a way to generate unique links and handle what happens when each is clicked on!). I dont think that is possible. The user onclick on the link could be redirected to new activity which will pull friend-requests from the server from the mapping availabe. The user could accept or reject the requests here. You see a single link will fail to provide functionality of multiple requests the user gets. Once the second user has one this, you can notify the first user of the same(maybe via GCM or by polling from the device(not efficient!)).
 I hope my interpretation of the task at hand was right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally something I was looking forward to. This topic was new to me and I was falling short of ideas of how to process it further, but, you guided me in the right direction. I am implementing it and let's see how things proceed.